# Random number generator comparing a list

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to compare a list of picked numbers to a list of randomly generated numbers. I want to know how many times it took to get the same numbers in the same sequence picked. I am using the choice() function which i have imported. Please see my code below. I seem to continue to get an infinite loop and never generate the same list as "my ticket"

My code below

```
from random import choice

    my_ticket = (9, 'z', 4, 0)
    lottery_numbs = ['a', 'z', 'i', 't', 'u', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]


    winning_numbers = []
    picked_sequences = []
    increment = 0

    while True:
        for pick in range(4):
            pick = choice(lottery_numbs)

            winning_numbers.append(pick)

        if winning_numbers in picked_sequences:
            continue
        else:
            picked_sequences.append(winning_numbers)

        if my_ticket in picked_sequences:
            print(increment)
            break
        else:
            winning_numbers = []
            print(increment)


        increment += 1

    print(winning_numbers)
    print(my_ticket)
    print(f"It took {increment} picks to pick my lottery numbers")
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the *types* of data that you're generating. What is `choice(lottery_numbs)` returning? What does `winning_numbers` contain? What are you comparing it against? If you have similar digits in different containers, you're not going to get a "match" unless you explicitly handle the containers.

Comment: so you cant compare a tuple to a list?

Comment: Thank you that was simple... I appreciate how you phrased that!

Comment: Nope, they are different types of data. (For example, you can't append to a tuple, but you can append to a list.)

Comment: Glad to hear it! Answering questions is only rewarding if you can help someone understand a new concept, and I'm always glad to hear if I have. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following is my take on your code.

Firstly, I changed your `my_ticket` into `winning_ticket` and made it into a list.

Then I changed your filtering of duplicate numbers inside current_ticket into a while loop, to ensure that the ticket will always contain 4 unique characters.

Then I converted your while true loop into a while condition on if the current ticket is the same as winning ticket.

Your main issue is the `my_ticket` being a tuple, the other minor issues are redundant for loop to filter duplicate, no guarantee on current ticket having 4 characters, variable namings, etc.

```py
from random import choice

winning_ticket = [9, 'z', 4, 0]
lottery_numbs = ['a', 'z', 'i', 't', 'u', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]


picks = 0
current_ticket = []

while current_ticket != winning_ticket:
    current_ticket = []

    while len(current_ticket) < 4:
        pick = choice(lottery_numbs)
        if pick not in current_ticket:
            current_ticket.append(pick)

    picks += 1

print(f"It took {picks} picks to pick my lottery numbers")
```